# How to show a content without creating node for it on Drupal site?

Tags: nodes, theming

I am creating a custom node page called node--mynode.tpl.php.
The code I'm putting in is `<p> test</p>`

Unfortunately nothing shows up on my Drupal site.
I have also added a node.tpl.php on the same folder as my node--mynode.tpl.php.
However I'm not sure if I have to add any code to the node.tpl.php?

Is it anything I need to add on my template.php?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: Yes I did. I was wondering maybe is there a code to add to the node.tpl.php?

Comment: double dash, assuming drupal 7, so `mynode` is the machine name of the content type or a numeric nid, right? and these files are sitting in your theme?  (if node.tpl.php is totally empty, chaos will most probably ensue btw)

Comment: can u mention the name of your content type and tpl you are created exactly?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but you do have a node of that content type, do you?

Comment: I didn't create any content type for that node. I just need to create a page programmatically with loads of javascript and php that I couldn't do on the CCK of Drupal. Is it not the right way to do it? Sorry I am a beginner on Drupal 7...

Comment: Just to explain a little bit more on what I need to achieve is create a product page for my Drupal 7 site. But I just want to avoid doing that by the admin site of Drupal.

Answer (score 3):

While not at all suggested or encouraged, if you really want to create a static page in drupal, you can fake it out by creating a `page--PATH.tpl.php` template, but just realize that while it will show up, behind the scenes drupal will be throwing 404 / not found errors.

See [Drupal 7 Template Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) for more information.

What I would suggest instead, though, is to look into Drupal's Menu System and create a callback for the page in question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I didn't realized that I needed to create a content type in order to create a node page... Now that I have created my content type called product, I could see on my site the result of my node--product.tpl.php. However I have one last question if you don't mind... I have an image field (machine name= field_image_1) in another content type called comments. So I am putting this code on my node--product.tpl.php "<?php print render($content['field_caption']);?>" but nothing shows again. Do you know the reason why? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: The only information available in `$content` in a node template is information available in the specific node, so unless you have the field from the other content type defined in that node type, and that field has been populated in the specific node itself, nothing will show up.

Comment: I've added an image field to the content type product (field_image_recipe) and tried the <?php print render($content['field_image_recipe']);?> but nothing shows up . I did upload an image to that field as well...

Comment: for debugging, put a `print_r($content, TRUE)` or its equivalent in there to see what you have to work with

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you cannot create content inside Drupal without creating nodes. That's against the very basic concept behind Content Management Systems.

If you need, however, a static HTML page, make just that - a static HTML page inside your Drupal installation, but without using any Drupal's systems. It will get served, files have precedence over Drupal.
**I strongly discourage this**, but it will work.

If are willing to add node, create one with fields you will most probably need to edit, like title, body and so on. This way you will be able to edit them on site if needed, archive, revision and so on. And you will be able to use [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) or [Views Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_field) to show other things along it: comments, image galleries and so on. Both projects are well documented, and works with each other if needed.

Comment: Ah great! It works now, I have created a content type called product (with 1 field body), and I can see the code from my node--product.tpl.php Thanks for this. Just a last question if you don't mind, I have an image field (machine name= field_image_1) in another content type called comments. So I am putting this code on my node--product.tpl.php  "<?php print render($content['field_caption']);?>" but nothing shows again. Do you know the reason why? Many thanks!

Comment: Yep, I know. The reason is $content contains only your current node. If you want to access other nodes, you need to invoke [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7). But to be honest, @Jimajamma answered this better than me. His approach is more difficult, but more flexible at the same time. And I'll edit my answer right away! Need to add references to it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll have a look at the node_load() function

Answer (score 0):

as per you are asking you need to put an function $content = node_load('nid'); . Then print the $content, you  can get the values of the node what you mentioned in nid. nid is nothing but the node id of the node which is having field_image_1 from another content type. for the current node you need to put another funtion $content = node_load(arg(1)); arg(1) is nothing but the current nid passing on the url. Finally you can print the current node(product) contents and also print the another content type contents(image field)..